# How to get the file uploading progress percentage of an external input?

Tags: javascript, input

I built a file upload input on an HTML page, and I am now trying to get the current status of every upload made on this input.

Note that I have limited possibilities on the input, as the page is built on a no-code tool, so the best for me would be to use an event listener on the input ID to trigger the script that will retrieve the upload progress.

Is it doable? If so, any guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.